# Can a computer in a network use its own DNS settings and bypass a router?

Tags: router, dns

If my home router is using OpenDNS, is it possible for a computer to override their own DNS settings and it would bypass all the OpenDNS rules?

Or since all traffic is coming via the home router, all DNS queries will be resolved by the router’s setup?

Comment: Since you are allowing both possibilities as an OR, then I find it utterly easiest to use the DNS server of my ISP. My main router has the ISP IP address, and gateway, and then two DNS servers from my ISP. works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

> If my home router is using OpenDNS, is it possible for a computer to override their own DNS settings and it would bypass all the OpenDNS rules?

Yes. The DNS server each device uses is configurable and exists in the network settings on each device.

> Or since all traffic is coming via the home router, all DNS queries will be resolved by the router’s setup?

No. Normally, your router will hand out the DNS configurations to your networked devices via DHCP. Typically the DNS IP address provided is that of the router. But there is nothing preventing changing the DNS setting on the device.

To prevent someone from bypassing your restrictions you’ll need to block port 53 TCP and UDP outbound. This will prevent network devices from communicating with other external DNS servers.  Even then, DNS is not a requirement for the proper operation of a TCP / IP network and there are plenty of other ways to bypass this type of restriction.

Comment: ideally I want to be able to block a list of websites per device, currently using opendns and my router I can't do multiple profiles of access control. any tips?